Django subquery with static VALUES expression
Is it possible using the Django ORM to write a subquery which SELECTs from a set of fixed values?
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  (
    SELECT
    new_ages.age
    FROM
    (VALUES ('homer', 35), ('marge', 34)) AS new_ages(name, age)
    WHERE new_ages.name = ages.name
  ) AS new_age
FROM
  ages
  ;

The output from such a query might be something like:
person_id  name    age
        1  homer   35
       42  marge   34
       99  bart    null

I know that the Django code would look something like this:
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from my_app.models import Person

Person.objects.annotate(age=Subquery(...(name=OuterRef("name")))

But what goes in the ...?

Django solves this with long Case(When(..))) expressions for "bulk updates", although these are not very "bulk".

Related: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/dictionary-lookups-for-the-database.html

As far as I know, you can't define such "in-memory" tables in Django, or at least not right now.
The sad reality is that Django's .bulk_update(…) implementation [Django-doc], which essentially is what you are doing here, has the same problem. It solves that in a bit of a "clumsy" way: a long CASE … WHEN … THEN … END sequence. We can do this the same way with:
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

new_ages = {'homer': 35, 'marge': 34}

Person.objects.annotate(
    age=Case(*[When(name=k, then=Value(v)) for k, v in new_ages.items()])
)
I wrote an article about this [django-antipatterns], but again, it is not a good way to do this. Perhaps the best way would even be to define a model where one can dump items into, and then let the JOIN do the work.

This is actually not terrible. I can't see how it's much worse than constructing the VALUES in memory (certainly the resulting SQL will probably be a similar length, right?) Maybe the problem is that the query planner won't see this as a join and do whatever optimisation magic it would do. But I think I like this solution anyway...

@LondonRob: the JOINing will not be done with a table, so with linear search, and so the entire thing is quadratic. This means that if new_ages contains a lot of elements, it can get quite slow.

So the caveat for this method probably goes: this works fine for small numbers of WHEN statements but will get slower as the number of cases increases. (FWIW our use case will be limited to tens of cases so we're ok!)

@LondonRob: yes, for ~10-100 items in new_ages it will likely not be a problem. The main problem is when dealing with thousands of cases.
